# Passing in access and secret keys through AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Due to certain enterprise limitations, I'm only able to access AWS through the command line, and I cannot set environment variables. I was wondering if there is any way to pass in my keys with the command in a manner like this:

`aws s3 cp <file> s3://testbucket --aws-access-key <accesskey> --aws-secret-key <secretkey>`

I noticed that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908036/passing-access-and-secret-key-aws-cli) is fairly similar, although it seems that the answers are either not applicable to my situation or referencing the ec2din command, which I could not translate into copying files to s3. I just get the response `Unknown options: --aws-access-key,--aws-secret-key`.

Comment: Why is it OK to use the CLI, but not the SDK? They both essentially do the same thing (make HTTPS calls to AWS endpoints).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AAAA AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BBB aws s3 cp <file> s3://testbucket
```

This will set the keys for this command only. If you need the keys for the session, export them like below:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AAAA ; export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BBB ; aws s3 cp <file> s3://testbucket
```

Comment: @DanMandel If you want the command to be unavailable in bash history, just add a space before it.

Comment: I receive the error `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<secretkey>": error=2, No such file or directory` and `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export": error=2, No such file or directory`. I think this is because I am running these commands through a scala program, which is why I am unable to set environment variables by exporting.

Comment: The "program" you want to run, then, is another shell to interpret the command as intended: `/bin/bash -c 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AAAA AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BBB aws s3 cp <file> s3://testbucket'`  Note the `'` quotes, they are needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering about that first syntax, using temporary variables for that command line only. If I try this: `NAME=RocketNuts echo "Hello $NAME, good day"` I'm getting this result: `Hello , good day`. If I insert a `;` before the echo, then it works, but then `$NAME` also still exists afterwards. Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Thanks man, it works, I only needed this for my local dynamodb table creation under docker

Answer (score 3):

Are you allowed to save the AK/SK to a file? (very much like an SSH private key would be saved in ~/.ssh/id_rsa for example)

If so, you can run the command `aws configure`, which will prompt for your AK and SK (plus default region and default output format). The credentials will be saved to ~/.aws/credentials, and the region and output (if you chose to specify them) will be saved to ~/.aws/config.

If you are *not* allowed to write your credentials to a file, be careful with commands passing credentials through the command like - those credentials might get into a "command history" file! In some shells, you can configure so that adding a space in front of a command will prevent it from being written into the history file.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass keys within `aws configure` itself, below is an example:

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id <accessKeyID>
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key <secretAccessKey>
```

then run your command:

```
aws <command> help
aws <command> <subcommand> help
```

If you want to have all of them in one line:

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id "xxx" && \
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "yyy" && \
aws s3 ls
```

Comment: What about the bucket name?

Answer (score 0):

add environmental variables in the project https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/

screen:
[image]

And then configure config .circleci/config.yml :

```
# deploy to aws s3
  deploy:
    docker: 
      - image: cibuilds/aws:1.15.73
    environment:
      aws_access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      aws_secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ./workspace
      - run: 
          name: Deploy to S3 if tests pass and branch is develop
          command: aws s3 sync workspace/public s3://your.bucket/ --delete
```